# Exibindo Resultados diferente de uma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela `CAIXA`, onde na coluna `TIPO` pode ter dois resultados, o `00` e o `99`, onde `00` é a abertura do terminal e `99` o fechamento.

Estou tentando criar uma query onde o resultado seja me evidenciar apenas as filiais (`COD_FILIAL`) onde não realizaram o fechamento do caixa.

Seria mais ou menos isso:

```
WHERE TIPO = 99 < TIPO = 00 and DATA between '20160101' and '20160101'
```

Mas não estou conseguindo passar este pensamento para SQL.

Comment: Pode colocar a estrutura completa da(s) tabelas?

Comment: Esses campos já não são suficientes @bruno?

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você teria uma tabela caixa parecida com isso:

```
| COD_FILIAL | TIPO | DATA     |
|------------|------|----------|
| 1          | 00   | 20160101 |
| 1          | 99   | 20160101 |
| 2          | 00   | 20160101 |
| 2          | 99   | 20160101 |
| 3          | 00   | 20160101 |
| 1          | 00   | 20160102 |
| 1          | 99   | 20160102 |
| 2          | 00   | 20160102 |
| 1          | 00   | 20160103 |
```

E você espera os seguintes resultados (as filias onde houve abertura de caixa em um determinado dia mas não teve fechamento):

```
| COD_FILIAL | TIPO | DATA     |
|------------|------|----------|
| 3          | 00   | 20160101 |
| 2          | 00   | 20160102 |
| 1          | 00   | 20160103 |
```

Considerando que sempre deve existir uma abertura de caixa para ter um fechamento, pense que os caixas sem fechamento são a diferença do subconjunto dos caixas fechados (a parte grifada em cinza):

[image: Conjunto]

Para pegar só a parte cinza, pense que você tem duas listas: as filias e dias com caixa aberto e as filias com caixa fechado. Ao juntar essas listas, tire a parte que houver intersecção e você terá os dias que os caixas ficaram abertos.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM CAIXA WHERE STATUS = '00') AS abertura
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CAIXA WHERE STATUS = '99') AS fechamento ON
  abertura.cod_filial = fechamento.cod_filial AND
  abertura.data = fechamento.data
WHERE fechamento.status IS NULL;
```

Veja a query rodando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b3550/7).

Para fazer essa query usei os conceitos de subquery e joins. Essa consulta pode ser feita de formas diferentes, usando uma CVE do SQL Server.

Deixo abaixo alguns links que podem te ajudar a entender melhor esses conceitos.

- [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)
- [T-SQL Subqueries: Onde e quando utilizar](http://www.devmedia.com.br/t-sql-subqueries-onde-e-quando-utilizar/32072)
- [WITH commom_value_expressions (CVE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Amigo, sua resposta resolveu 90% da minha questão, veja o codigo original:
__________________________________________________
SELECT
 Abertura.CODIGO_FILIAL, Abertura.DATA, Abertura.TIPO_LANCAMENTO_CAIXA
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM LOJA_CAIXA_LANCAMENTOS WHERE TIPO_LANCAMENTO_CAIXA = '00') AS Abertura
  left JOIN (SELECT * FROM LOJA_CAIXA_LANCAMENTOS WHERE TIPO_LANCAMENTO_CAIXA = '99') AS Fechamento ON
  Abertura.CODIGO_FILIAL = Fechamento.CODIGO_FILIAL AND
  Abertura.DATA = Fechamento.DATA
WHERE
 Fechamento.TIPO_LANCAMENTO_CAIXA IS NULL AND Abertura.DATA BETWEEN '20160826' AND '20160826'

Comment: Porem, agora ficou a seguinte questão, tem algumas filiais que a abertura do caixa('00') ainda nao foi integrada, ou seja, eu nao tenho integrado nem a abertura e nem o fechamento, e ai este resultado não exibe essas filiais que não tem a abertura do caixa integrada

Comment: Lembrando que o diferencial neste caso, é que a abertura e o fechamento não foram integrados, mas a filial já tem registro na tabela LOJA_VENDA.

É importado primeiro a tabela LOJA_VENDA e depois a LOJA_CAIXA_LANCAMENTO, sendo assim eu tenho registro de venda, mas por um erro no recebimento, ainda não importei os movimentos de caixa.

Comment: @EliRodriguesdaSilva isso já é outra questão. Faça um [tour] e entenda como funciona a comunidade. A ideia é ter perguntas que sejam úteis para outras pessoas, e não algo que vá solucionar em 100% todos seus problemas (que é esse o caso que você está querendo chegar).